# В чём отличие между аналитическим методом рядов для решения задачи Коши для ОДУ и численным методом разложения в ряд Тейлора?

Tags: численные-методы

Я так понимаю, общая формула (7.7) представляет собой аналитический метод, тогда как выглядит численный? [image: 1]

[image: 2]

Или то, когда я решаю конкретную задачу на каком-то примере - считаю производные до нужного порядка, реализовываю, а после, по заданному шагу, вывожу результат в табличном виде и есть применение численного метода решения задачи Коши?

Или тут совершенно другая идея? Объясните пожалуйста, а то практика давно сдана, а теория повисла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отличие главным образом в том, что аналитический метод работает, если выполнены условия теоремы Коши-Ковалевской о существовании и единственности решения.

Однако, для реальных задач эти условия чаще всего не выполнены, так что метод аналитического решения к ним не подходит.

Однако, если искать решение, например, в пространстве Соболева, все прекрасно находится численным методом.

Итого, если для задачи выполняются условия теоремы К-К., численный метод выдаст на ней то же, что и поиск классического решения.

Если же не выполняются, поиск классического решения применять нельзя, а сходимость численного метода требуется обосновывать уже иными способами.

В численном методе идея решения отличается от аналитического.

В аналитическом методе вы буквально находите коэффициенты, с помощью которых можно собрать ряд, являющийся разложением решения данной задачи.

В численном методе, само уравнение заменяется на так называемый *дискретный аналог*, который позволяет превратить уравнение с частными производными в систему линейных алгебраических уравнений.

Дискретный же аналог получается путем замены производных функции на различные *разностные шаблоны*, если мы говорим о методе конечных разностей.

Comment: А можно ли считать метод Эйлера за численный метод разложения в ряд Тейлора?

Comment: Да. Некоторые разностные шаблоны в методе конечных разностей тоже получаются путем взятия первого - второго членов из разложения в ряд Тейлора